# i cannot compile my java program in command prompt

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command-prompt, javac

I have set the path in environment variables, but when I compile a simple hello.java file using command prompt:

```
javac hello.java
```

it gives me error:

```
javac: file not found: hello.java
```

I have tried to open command prompt in same directory and then run it,
I don't know what is wrong

Comment: I'm unclear as to if the issue is that the `javac` program is not found or if your source file `hello.java` is not found. Which is it? If you think it is an environment problem try running `env` from your command line and see what your variables are set to.

Comment: when i typed env in command prompt it says env is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 3):

Try running the below command

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin
```

If it successful, try running your file using javac. If it doesn't work change environment variables path to above path to include JDK.

Let me know if either of them doesn't work

Comment: i found my error, it was due to wrong naming of file, i used to save hello.java in text editor but it was saved as hello.java.txt. So i configured it to just hello.java and it compiled successfully!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `javac` is working correctly, but it can't find `hello.java`. Before executing `javac hello.java`, execute `dir | findstr .java` (or `ls | grep *.java` if aren't using Windows). Make sure that `hello.java` is listed. If it isn't, then your command prompt opened in the wrong folder, and you will need to used `cd` to get where the file is located.

Comment: i found my error, it was due to wrong naming of file, i used to save hello.java in text editor but it was saved as hello.java.txt. So i configured it to just hello.java and it compiled successfully!